# HTTP error: 403 while parsing a website

Tags: postgresql, python-2.7, beautifulsoup, mechanize

So I'm trying to parse from this website http://dl.acm.org/dl.cfm . This website doesn't allow web scrapers, so hence I get an `HTTP error: 403 forbidden.`

I'm using python, so I tried mechanize to fill the form (to automate the filling of the form or a button click), but then again I got the same error.

I can't even open the html page using `urllib2.urlopen()` function, it gives the same error.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the website doesn't allow web scrapers/bots, you shouldn't be using bots on the site to begin with.

But to answer your question, I suspect the website is blocking urllib's default user-agent. You're probably going to have to spoof the user-agent to a known browser by crafting your own request.

```
headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (X11; U; Linux i686) Gecko/20071127 Firefox/2.0.0.11"}
req = urllib2.Request("http://dl.acm.org/dl.cfm", headers=headers)
urllib2.urlopen(req)
```

EDIT: I tested this and it works. The site is actively blocking based on user-agents to stop badly made bots from ignoring robots.txt

Comment: Its actually for research purpose, data analysis, so i'm not doing anything illegal.

Comment: Well, if this solved your problem, please accept it.

Whether or not it's for research purposes, ignoring robots.txt, while not explicitly illegal, can be considered trespassing and damaging. There have been several court cases in the past where bypassing these blocks have been considered akin to "picking a lock." Whatever you're doing, you may want to ask for permission first and tread carefully.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the warning, i will definitely ask their permission!